# Wired "Not Connected" icon in system tray instead of Wireless "Connected"

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, wired-networking

I've been getting this weird problem as of late:

[image]

It seems as if I'm not connected to any network - be it wired or wireless, even though I am connected via wireless ("bamba" has internet access), and can surf the web.

I'm running Windows 7 X64  on a Sony Vaio 3-4 years old.

What can cause this?

**Note:** *Just Figured out I can't connect to any wired network as well - tried plugging the laptop into the socket in the wall using an ethernet cable and I can't get a connection. Related?*

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling both your wired and wireless drivers?

Comment: Hiw can I figure out which ones I'm Running?

Comment: http://esupport.sony.com/p/select-system.pl?DIRECTOR=DRIVER

Comment: Check your network adapters, is anything disabled? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-network-adapter-problems#1TC=windows-7